# Spring Batch Process ZipEntries in a ZipFile in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Zip file that has many entries, I want to process it with Spring Batch. Reading the documentation I've not seen how can I split execution based on zip entry.

Without Spring Batch

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("./large-files.zip"); 
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        int entriesCount = 0;
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            entriesCount++;
            processInParallel(zipFile, entries.nextElement());
           // executorService.submit(()-> { //do something with entries.nextElement() }); 
        }
```

[image]

How can I acheive this with Spring Batch ?

Comment: You can try this [ZipMultiResourceItemReader](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples-readers/blob/master/src/main/java/de/langmi/spring/batch/examples/readers/file/zip/ZipMultiResourceItemReader.java) implementation in a multi-threaded step.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I still don't understand it, and I think it is still sequential Thanks for the code :)

Comment: The reader is sequential (all readers are sequential BTW), but you can use it in a multi-threaded step to process entries in parallel using multiple threads.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks a lot, I am new to Spring Batch, and I can't understand it's processing steps, does it work like Apache Beam the output of step 1 is the input of step 2 ?

Comment: I don't know about beam's processing model, but for Spring Batch, step1 will run and complete then step2 will run and complete etc (of course you can run them in parallel if you want). But items don't "flow" from a step to the next one before the completion of the first step. The entire step should be complete before the next one starts. You can of course make step1's output as input of step2 using a staging table or temporary file, but step2 will start only after all items of step1 have been read and written. Hope this clarifies the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring's TaskExecutor to enable parallel processing. In your itemReader, please make sure you have a synchronized method to make sure that no two threads would fetch the same file from .zip to process.

```
/**
 * Enables parallel processing based on configured number of threads
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
    return taskExecutor;
}


@Bean
protected Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<DOMAIN_OBJ, DOMAIN_OBJ>chunk(1).reader(myReader)
            .chunk(1).processor(myProcessor).chunk(1).writer(myWriter).chunk(1).taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(maxThreads).build();
}
```